# Set content type xml not working in servlet response

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

So I have a servlet which get the response from another servlet in order to do some formatting, generate a pdf from that and encode to base64:

```
//setting response to get xml
response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

String pdf = "";
final StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url); //another Servlet

//getting response from another servlet
if (dispatcher != null) {
    dispatcher.include(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
        private PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(buffer);
        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return writer;
        }
    });
}

String jspResponse = buffer.toString();

/* 
 *  do some stuff with jspResponse
 *  and putting into Document doc
 */

try {
    //generating pdf content and encoding to base64
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
    renderer.layout();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    renderer.createPDF(baos);

    byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray());
    pdf = new String(base64);
}
catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

request.setAttribute("pdf", pdf);
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/new.jsp");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

And the jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<MSG-S>
    <PDF>
        <E>
            <!-- variable containing a string with 40K+ -->
            <BASE64>${pdf}</BASE64>
        </E>
    </PDF>
</MSG-S>
```

The problem is that I'm still getting a content-type text/html:

[image]

Comment: Don't know about your problem, but your first two lines are redundant, i.e. the second line overrides the first: `response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1"); response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");`

Comment: @Andreas I'm aware about that but already tried with just one line and still the same (both cases).

Answer (score 0):

I added only: `response.setContentType("text/xml");`, and I do get the **contentType** as **XML**.

[image]